# Save canvas to image with all its object and back to canvas with all objects back for editing them

Tags: html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabrics JS for adding objects on canvas and then saving it in form of image. Now i want bring the image back to edit mode inside canvas.

You can get detailed idea about it at http://www.13thandmars.com/logo_studio/builder.html?project_id=17b36372c43c04044dd804454dfdf6e8

Add text will add an object to tshirt in above link.

Comment: Do I need to convert image to SVG?

Comment: Fabricjs give natively the serialization/deserialization of canvas, what is concretely the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can save canvas as JSON and then can load it back from JSON

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(['left', 'top', 'lockMovementX', 'lockMovementY']));
canvas.loadFromJSON(myJson, function () {
    //render the canvas
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. it worked
But font on canvas are not loading..
they are loading once I click on it...

Comment: You need to add all the object properties which you are using in the `canvas.toJSON` like i have added as an example `top`, `left` etc

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken you say that the font property is missing?

if this is you problem please take a look ,
 fabric DOES NOT convert all the object properties to Json when you convert the canvas with canvas.toJSON() , so when you are going to get back your canvas , the objects will not be complete (your custom properties will missing),

for example : myObj.material , myObj.size, myObj.clotheType etc.

you have to say to the prototype toObject function which properties you want to be converted also with canvas.toJSON(), in your code, the following is a snippet of my code:

```
        fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
            return function() {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                    objectId: this.objectId,//my custom property
                    _controlsVisibility:this._getControlsVisibility(),//i want to keep controlsVisibility for my reasons
                    typeTable:this.typeTable,//my custom property
                    txtType:this.txtType, //my custom property
                    customOptions:this.customOptions//my custom object property
                });
            };
```

i hope that helps.

Comment: Done the problem was font was not loading properly because link to google font was not given properly.. Thanx