# How to get an object identifier in fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

How to get an object identifier in fabricjs?
For example

```js
var text = new fabric.IText('hello world', { left: mouse1X, top: mouse1Y });
    
ID = text.get???
```

This identifier should be present in

```js
JSON.stringify(canvas) 
canvas.loadFromJSON()
```

identifier should be present in the `JSON.stringify(canvas)` `canvas.loadFromJSON()`

Comment: Please use the edit label above to edit your question.

Answer (score 24):

When you create an object, pass along the options an `id` attribute:

```js
var obj = fabric.Object({id: 'myid'});
```

or add at runtime:

```js
obj.id = 'myid';
```

When saving to JSON use the `propertiesToInclude` parameter to specify you want to save it:

```js
obj.toJSON(['myid', 'others...']);
```

or

```js
canvas.toJSON(['myid', 'others...']);
```

Loading back will be automatic.

Answer (score 3):

There are not id attributes on the objects, but you can create your own.
like this:

```js
var msg = 'hello world';
var myId = 1;

var text = new fabric.IText(msg, { 
    left: mouse1X, 
    top: mouse1Y,
    id: myId //my custom property
});
    
canvas.add(text);
    
//get id value
console.log(text.get('id'));
//OR
console.log(text.id));
    
//change id value
text.set('id',5);
//OR
text.id = 5;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: id in your example will not be saved in JSON

Comment: i am afraid that your question was how to have an id on fabricjs objects, and not on how you save it on json. i answered that and it is correct solution. but if you need to save your properties on json take a look on my answer here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052223/save-canvas-to-image-with-all-its-object-and-back-to-canvas-with-all-objects-bac/30071209#30071209 
if my answer helped you please tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id when creating any object like this:

```js
// functions that generates an id
function generateId(type) {
    return `${type}-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`;
}

const rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
    id: generateId('rect'),
    left: 150,
    top: 45,
});
```

So, you can reset ids by passing the reviver callback to `loadFromJSON`.

```js
// function to be passed as reviver callback
function resetObjectsIds(o, object) {
    object.set({ id: generateId(object.get('type')) });
}

// when loading json...
canvas.loadFromJSON(
    canvasJson,
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    resetObjectsIds, // here is the reviver callback function
);
```

Now, every time you save or load the canvas, it will have ids.

Comment: i does not work with typescript, since that id property is not part of the interface